# no match for ‘operator==’, comparing object to NULL

Tags: c++

Hello I am having a problem with my current project.
I am getting the following error on compiler:
error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘Post’ and ‘long int’)
   if (posts[i] == NULL)

on the following function:

```
bool Thread::createPost(const string& title, const string& creator) {
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if (posts[i] == NULL) {
        posts[i] = new Post(title, creator);
        post_number++;
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
}
```

So I am trying to check if the next object has been created and if not, to create a new one and apparently I am comparing an object of the "Post" class to a long int which is NULL(?), is there a way to fix that?

Comment: What does your `posts` variable look like? Best guess it's `Post posts[N]` i.e. an array of structures not pointers to structures. With your null check and the new you possibly meant `Post* posts[N]`.

Comment: @Jaa-c it is a member of another class. It is an array of objects of a class, which is declared on another class.

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` (more specifically, `nullptr`) is a valid value for a pointer. When you declare an array of objects, all objects will be default-constructed for you as part of the process of creating your array. Hence all `posts[i]`s are always constructed.

If you want to make an array that is only partially filled, use an array of pointers, and operator `new` to create objects.

Better yet, use `std::vector<Post>` and insert as many objects as needed. This way you wouldn't have to check if an object is initialized or not, and use iteration up to the size of the array.

Comment: So, once I create the array, the objects are created by the default constructor, so the array is filled with objects?

Comment: @cyvous That is correct, if you create an array of objects, not pointers, all objects are created upfront.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you have something like:

```
Post posts[100];
```

(Well, it would be nice if you actually posted the code, so we wouldn't have to guess.)

You can do something like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Post> posts[100];
```

This is closest to what you already have, but it is a bit weird.

You could also just use a `std::vector`, and just never use null for your posts, like this:

```
std::vector<Post> posts;

posts.push_back(Post{title, creator});
```

But you will need to learn the difference between pointer types and non-pointer types.

P.S. You should be using `nullptr` instead of `NULL` these days.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes that's exactly what I have, since it is a project I am not allowed to use std::vector

Comment: PS. You should be using emplace_back rather than push_back

Comment: @LokiAstari: I try to leave micro-optimizations out of answers on Stack Overflow.